# How secure storage apps woks

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes, file-security

I want to make a mobile application using Flutter like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enchantedcloud.photovault

but I don't know how to keep the data actually safe

I have used aes_crpyt package ( https://pub.dev/packages/aes_crypt ) which allows me to encrpyt and decrpyt files
but how can I retrieve the data to be shown in the application without being decrypted as normal files which can be opened using any explorer which can access root files

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this package: [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). From the documentation:

> - Keychain is used for iOS
> - AES encryption is used for Android. AES secret key is encrypted with RSA and RSA key is stored in KeyStore

This way your data can be saved in a `SharedPreferences` fashion in a safer way through encryption.

Sample syntax:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

// Create storage
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

// Read value 
String value = await storage.read(key: key);

// Read all values
Map<String, String> allValues = await storage.readAll();

// Delete value 
await storage.delete(key: key);

// Delete all 
await storage.deleteAll();

// Write value 
await storage.write(key: key, value: value);
```

Since any database's purpose is to only store pure informational organized data. It's not suitable for storing large files such as media, documents, or images. There are 2 alternatives:

1. Upload the encrypted file to Firebase, then save the encrypted path to DB
2. Save encrypted file to local storage, then store the encrypted path

I recommend the 1st method since you can avoid saving the encrypted files at local and risking chance to expose it to other users.

Comment: It encrypts only string. I want to encrypt files like images and videos

Comment: OK, I have encrypted the file and saved it in local storage, but when the user opens the application I have to decrypt the to be shown.
It can be accessed using root explorer. How can I prevent that?